# Trying to receive dynamicaly generated XML from php file, and display it using jQuery

Tags: php, xml, jquery

I decided to dive into AJAX with help of jQuery, and I'm stuck already...

Anyway! I have a php file, that when called produces the following XML:

```
<response>
<status>1</status>
<character><charname>Loupax</charname>
<charId>112</charId>
<charLvl>1</charLvl>
<charStats>
<statsId>63</statsId>
<strength>13</strength>
<dexterity>14</dexterity>
<physique>15</physique>
<defence>12</defence>
</charStats>
</character>
</response>
```

What I want to do, is to display these elements on my html page (duh!) but I can't figure out the jQuery...

my jQuery is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#showBtn").mouseup(function(){
var charname=$("#showInp").val();
//var data="";
$.ajax({
url: 'ajaxgetchar.php',
data: "showInp=Loupax",
dataType:text,
type:'POST',
success: function(data){
$('.result').xml(data);
alert("Success!!!");
};
});
});
});
```

and the markup is
    `<input type="button" value="Show character" id="showBtn" name="showBtn"/>`

The problem is that, no matter how many times I click the button, I don't get the alert I was supposed to get...

Any help would be appreciated... I'm a total newb in XML/jQuery/ajax, and I'm pretty sure it's something dumb... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.xml method doesn't exist?

try

```
$('.result').text(data);
```

Also try alert(data), to see if it even returns anything.

```
$("#showBtn").click(function() {

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "ajaxgetchar.php",
   data: "showInp=Loupax",
   success: function(data){
     alert(data);
   }
 });

});
```

Comment: Does the same thing... No reaction when I click the btn... Isn't there a way to debug this thing???

Comment: All this trouble for a semicolon? Duh, I knew it was dumb... It worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd use `$("#showBtn").click()` instead of `$("#showBtn").mouseup()`. Second, you should remove the extra `;` after the success function. Third, download the Firebug extension for Firefox to see if it's actually making the ajax call and if so what the response is. If you get an error response code then the success function won't be called. To catch the error use the `error(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)` setting in your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajaxgetchar.php',
  data: "showInp=Loupax",
  dataType:text,
  type:'POST',
  error: function(xhr, status, error){
    // Handle error here
  },
  success: function(data){
    $('.result').xml(data);
    alert("Success!!!");
  }
});
```

Comment: No good... I changed the handler from mouseUp to click() (even though I tested it, and the handler fires)... I'm downloading firebug, and I'll be back!

Comment: Note Sarah's answer related to the extra `;` . This semicolon is a simple syntax-error, that's why nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

so it seems like you're getting an error, add an error: function(request, status, errthrown) { alert(errthrown); } to your code to see what the error is being thrown. You might need to adjust that function, I'm just doing it quickly from memory..

more details [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):